Flutter Date and Time Picker not showing up
I don't have that much experience with Flutter,the showDatePicker and the showTimePicker don't show up when i hit the onTap button.I don't know it's about the Android Studio and the Emulator or about the codes. Please help me if possible,thank you.
Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              DateTimeWidget(titleText: 'Date',
                  valueText: dateProv.toString(),
                  iconSection: CupertinoIcons.calendar,
                onTap: () async {
                final DateTime? getValue = await showDatePicker(context: context, initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                    firstDate: DateTime(2021),lastDate: DateTime(2030));
                if(getValue != null) {
                  final format = DateFormat.yMd();
                  ref.read(dateProvider.notifier).update((state) => format.format(getValue));
                }
                },
          ),
              const Gap(22),
              DateTimeWidget(titleText: 'Time',
                valueText: ref.watch(timeProvider),
                iconSection: CupertinoIcons.clock,
                onTap: () async{
                final TimeOfDay getTime = showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: TimeOfDay.now()) as TimeOfDay;

                if(getTime != null) {
                  ref.read(timeProvider.notifier).update((state) => getTime.format(context));
                }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),

And this is the DateTimeWidget codes
class DateTimeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const DateTimeWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.titleText,
    required this.valueText,
    required this.iconSection,
    required this.onTap,
  });

  final String titleText;
  final String valueText;
  final IconData iconSection;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child:Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(titleText,style: AppStyle.headingOne,
          ),
          const Gap(6),
          Material(
            child: Ink(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.shade200,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              child: InkWell(

                splashColor: Colors.amber,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                onTap: () =>onTap,
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12,vertical:12 ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent,
                    borderRadius:  BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  ),
                  child: Row(children: [
                    Icon(iconSection),
                    const Gap(6),
                    Text(valueText),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],),
    );
  }
}

I've tried to change Ink and Inkwell classes but it doesn't work.

You just forgot to add brackets "()" inside InkWell's onTap callback. So your function is never called and performed. Just add brackets behind onTap and everything will be working fine.
onTap: () => onTap(),

instead of:
onTap: () => onTap,

